# Do I need to use a Transactional Email Service Provider to send emails with Django?

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, transactional-email

**Context**

1. I would like to send transactional Email with Django.
2. I understand that there are Transactional Email Service Provider (ESP) that faciliatates this endeavour.
3. The obvious issue I see with this is the cost associated with it. (I know there ESP with tier plans for small amounts of emails)

**Questions**

So, I have a few questions regarding this topic:

- Do I need a Transactional Email Service Provider to send emails through Django?
- What are the pros and cons of using an ESP for transactional emails in Django?
- If I decide to do it on my own (without using a ESP), does it scale well?
- What other issues can you see, that I'm not aware of, and you think they might be relevant?

**Final question**

- If my conclusion would be **not** **to use** an ESP, what steps should I take to send emails through Django?

I've looked at a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/hpr3hq/sending_sign_up_emails_do_i_need_a_transactional/) where they discuss this topic. But almost everyone keeps recommending using an ESP.

Comment: If you want your mail to be delivered even somewhat reliably, you will probably need a service these days. Setting up your own email-sending server is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not required to use a third party email service.  You can configure [Django for email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/) with an SMTP server that you install yourself on the server of your choosing, for example Google "smtp server self hosted" to find many products that do this, e.g. [sendmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail).

HOWEVER...

- third party email hosts are much less likely to be marked as "spam"
- third party email hosts offer free tiers and are relatively inexpensive
- third party emails have zero maintenance costs
- if you have email needs that are larger than a single server can handle, you will end up re-inventing the wheel and building some form of a cluster  unless you find a self-hosted product that has this feature

Comment: I know undersand that what I looking for was "Self-Hosted Email Server". The Django reference was irrelevant since this would be applied to any Web Framework.